# react antd - TimePicker.RangePicker, preset end time based on start time

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using `Antd` `TimePicker.RangePicker` and I am trying to customise that the end time will automatically set based on the start time.

For example, if I send start time "8 am", the end time will automatically set to "9 am".

Is that possible? I checked the document and did not find anything fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onChange` and setting value based on changed value as shown in below example

Check this out :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { TimePicker } from "antd";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [valus, setValues] = useState<[dayjs.Dayjs, dayjs.Dayjs] | undefined>([
    dayjs("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss"),
    dayjs("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss")
  ]);

  return (
    <TimePicker.RangePicker
      onChange={(vals) => setValues(vals)}
      value={[valus[0], valus[1].add(1, "hour")]}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Codesandbox** : https://codesandbox.io/s/time-range-picker-antd-5-0-2-forked-5ojpft

Comment: thanks for your answer. I actually found out what I want is called `onCalendarChange`, which will trigger even when you just change either start or end. `onChange` on the other hand, only trigger when you done with both start and finish.